# Override "animation-fill-mode: forwards" by adding class

Tags: css, css-animations

Why we can't override "forwards animation"? I added a simple example. Cannot override even using `!important`.

```js
// click and add the blue class
document.querySelector(".box").addEventListener("click", e => {
  e.target.classList.add("blue");
  console.log("blue class added");
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: pink;
  animation: change-color .3s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes change-color {
  to {
    background: green;
  }
}

.blue {
  background: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: because animation always win in such case

Comment: by the way, you want to know the *why* (not easy) or only a fix (easy)?

Comment: only fix enough

Comment: The example seems to work on my side. User attempted to color it blue on click, correct? That's exactly what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be fixed using different methods.

If you are able to adjust the animation you can consider CSS variables:

```js
// click and add the blue class
document.querySelector(".box").addEventListener("click", e => {
  e.target.classList.add("blue");
  console.log("blue class added");
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: pink;
  animation: change-color .3s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes change-color {
  to {
    background: var(--c,green);
  }
}

.blue {
  --c: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Or do it differently where you don't need the use of forwards

```js
// click and add the blue class
document.querySelector(".box").addEventListener("click", e => {
  e.target.classList.add("blue");
  console.log("blue class added");
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: green;
  animation: change-color .3s linear;
}

@keyframes change-color {
  from {
    background: pink;
  }
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

In case you cannot adjust the animation you can try to add another layer on the top (using box-shadow, pseudo element, etc)

```js
// click and add the blue class
document.querySelector(".box").addEventListener("click", e => {
  e.target.classList.add("blue");
  console.log("blue class added");
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: pink;
  animation: change-color .3s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes change-color {
  to {
    background: green;
  }
}

.blue {
  box-shadow:0 0 0 500px inset blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

---

You can also only animate the background-color and add the blue coloration with a  gradient:

```js
// click and add the blue class
document.querySelector(".box").addEventListener("click", e => {
  e.target.classList.add("blue");
  console.log("blue class added");
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: pink;
  animation: change-color .3s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes change-color {
  to {
    background-color: green;
  }
}

.blue {
  background-image:linear-gradient(blue,blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```